# Installation of Oracle 10.2.0.4 in windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, oracle

I have a problem in installingthe oracle database 10.2.0.4 in windows server 2003 environment, when I clicked the installer it always says "...\setup.exe isa valid, but is for a machine type other than the current machine". I also try to install other version of oracle such as oracle 10.2.0.5 but I got the same error. Please help me to solve this problem, thank you in advance.

Comment: is this 32bit vs 64bit, can you check versions of windows and oracle?

Comment: need more details about the OS you are installing on

Answer (score 1):

The error that you're getting tells me that you're trying to install a 64-bit program on a 32-bit operating system.